What's the highest ISP that a chemical rocket could achieve without using propellants maintained at cryogenic temperatures?
This is related to my earlier question about capturing an asteroid. If you wanted to place an interceptor rocket in space and the purpose of that rocket is to wait for a long time, and then launch to quickly intercept a passing object, that rocket could not be fueled up with cryogenic propellants as they would boil off. So, what's the best ISP that could be achieved with non-cryogenic propellants? Anything goes - I don't care how toxic the propellants are for this particular mission. The best solution simply needs the interceptor to have lots of thrust and a high total delta-v while achieving a long mission life by circumventing the boil-off problem somehow.

The various Mars sample return programs may have some relevant case studies on this, since they have a very similar mission profile.

Based on the book Ignition! the answer to this is probably unknown because we stopped researching the stuff that was so insanely toxic or so dangerous to handle that it couldn't be reasonably used.

If you're really interested in cost-no-object performance, use cryopropellants and simple depot them in space. Yes, it will boil off, but as long as your depot continually resupplies the rocket and you don't let the depot run dry, it can fire on short notice (pretty much as quickly as you can cut the fuel lines) and with high thrust.

The exotic stuff is mostly cryogenic. The direction in research today is more towards green propellants.  For a long term storable missile you are left with good old hydrazine / nitrogen tetroxide with its Isp in the low 300s.  The military uses solids for the type of application you have in mind (a missile that sits around for years and needs to go at a moment's notice) but those Isp's are 2/3 of the hydrazine / NTO value.
This is not the biggest problem with your concept, but it is a problem.
Advanced Chemical Propulsion Study (2005)
